# Design pattern for buffering pipeline input to PowerShell cmdlet

Tags: powershell, design-patterns

I occasionally encounter situations where it makes sense to support pipeline input to a Cmdlet but the operations I wish to do (e.g. database access) make sense to batch up on a sensible number of objects.

A typical way to achieve this appears to be something like the following:

```
function BufferExample {
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Example of filling and using an intermediate buffer.
#>
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
    $InputObject
)

BEGIN {
    $Buffer = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList(10)
    function _PROCESS {
        # Do something with a batch of items here.
        Write-Output "Element 1 of the batch is $($Buffer[1])"
        # This could be a high latency operation such as a DB call where we 
        # retrieve a set of rows by primary key rather than each one individually.

        # Then empty the buffer.
        $Buffer.Clear()
    }
}

PROCESS {
    # Accumulate the buffer or process it if the buffer is full.
    if ($Buffer.Count -ne $Buffer.Capacity) {    
        [void]$Buffer.Add($InputObject)        
    } else {
        _PROCESS 
    }
}

END {
     # The buffer may be partially filled, so let's do something with the remainder.
    _PROCESS
}
}
```

Is there a less "boilerplate" way to do this?

One method may be to write the function which I call "_PROCESS" here to accept array argument(s) but not pipeline input and then for the cmdlet exposed to the user to be a proxy function built to buffer the input and pass on the buffer as described in
[Proxy commands](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/03/01/proxy-functions-spice-up-your-powershell-core-cmdlets/).

Alternatively I could dot source dynamic code in the body of the cmdlet I wish to write to support this functionality, however this seems error prone and potentially hard to debug / understand.

Answer (score 2):

I made a re-usable cmdlet from your example.

```
function Buffer-Pipeline {
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    $Size = 10,
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
    $InputObject
)
    BEGIN {
        $Buffer = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList($Size)
    }

    PROCESS {
        [void]$Buffer.Add($_)

        if ($Buffer.Count -eq $Size) {    
            $b = $Buffer;
            $Buffer = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList($Size)
            Write-Output -NoEnumerate $b
        }
    }

    END {
     # The buffer may be partially filled, so let's do something with the remainder.
        if ($Buffer.Count -ne 0) {  
            Write-Output -NoEnumerate $Buffer
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
@(1;2;3;4;5) | Buffer-Pipeline -Size 3 | % { "$($_.Count) items: ($($_ -join ','))" }
```

Output:

```
3 items: (1,2,3)
2 items: (4,5)
```

Another example:

```
1,2,3,4,5 | Buffer-Pipeline -Size 10 | Measure-Object

Count    : 2
```

Processing each batch:

```
 1,2,3 | Buffer-Pipeline -Size 2 | % { 
    $_ | % { "Starting batch of $($_.Count)" } { $_ * 100 } { "Done with batch of $($_.Count)" }
}

Starting batch of 2
100
200
Done with batch of 2
Starting batch of 1
300
Done with batch of 1
```

Comment: Cmdlets that accept pipeline input are going to unroll the arrays aren’t they?  What happens if you pipe the output of Buffer-Pipeline in to Measure-Object?

Comment: Thanks to the magic of `-NoEnumerate`, it returns a count of 2 in this example. =)

Comment: Ha ha. Touché. The point though isn’t about chunking things up and passing those chunks down the pipeline (easy) but having a given cmdlet process in batches rather than one object at a time.  I think the correct way to do this is with a proxy command approach, but I’m certainly open to other suggestions.

Comment: Well once you have the chunks you can use the `Begin`, `Process` and `End` scritpblock arguments to `Foreach-Object`? See the example I just added.
`

Comment: How does this solve the problem?  In case it’s not clear I’m looking for this batching behaviour to be an intrinsic property of a given command - not a separate cmdlet. The dummy _PROCESS approach I outline does this, but it’s ugly. In other words - imagine a cmdlet that retrieves objects from a database based on a key - and it accepts pipeline input.  I want the cmdlet to accumulate a large set of keys (e.g. 100) and then issue a single SQL query with these 100 keys in the WHERE clause, retrieving a batch of results.  The user should not need to know about the batching.

Answer (score 1):

The nature of the pipeline puts some constraints on (easily) doing this the way you'd like, mostly because a `Process` block is designed to receive (and process) a single object.

If you want to buffer all objects, that's fairly simple; you just collect all the objects in an array or other collection within your `Process` block, and then do all the work in the `End` block; similar to the way a cmdlet like `Sort-Object` would handle it.

In the case of buffering for the sake of the underlying resource, like a web-based API, or your example of DB access, I think the approach you take will need to be situation-specific. There's unlikely to be a great general way to achieve it.

---

One of those approaches is to split the operation into 2 (maybe more?) functions.

For example I write some functions to send metrics to Graphite. I split the functions up between `Format-Graphite` and `Out-Graphite`; the former generates a properly formatted metric string, based on the parameters and the pipeline, while the latter sends string(s) to the Graphite collector. It allows the client code to be a bit more versatile in how it gets and generates it data because it can pipe to `Format-Graphite`, or make individual calls to it without worrying that the network portion will be inefficient. The client code does not have to deal with manually collecting its own data just to avoid that. Not the best example without code to demo but I can't post that code right now.

---

Another approach for things where the "expensive" part of a single operation is the initialization and tear down code is to just do that stuff in `Begin` and `End` and then use `Process` normally.

For example making dozens of database calls over a single connection you established in `Begin` may not be so bad, may even be preferable to doing something like building a big SQL string and sending it all at once.

---

Ultimately I think you might be better off looking at each individual use case and determining the best approach for your needs, balancing performance/efficiency and ease/intuitiveness of invoking the code.

If you have a specific use case and post a question about that, I'd like to read it; send me a link.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I don't want to do things entirely in the End block (in which case I would probably use the $input automatic variable) as I don't know how big the input stream will be.  I'd like a happy medium between the extremes of processing individual objects sequentially and buffering the entire input.

For now I have settled on an Ise Snippet for the body of the function, but an intermediate generic "buffer" function may be the way to go.

Comment: A specific use case would just be a high latency transaction such as a database call.  DB  calls can have a latency of ~200ms, this can kill performance for a large sequence of calls. It's far better to queue them up and send a single query with a more complex WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is one of the best approach you are using.

But still as you are looking for better debugging , I believe you can introduce some LOGS inside the function with a desired log file location.

Further, for dot sourcing you can still code Dot Source reference and call the function which is inside the other script and you can wrap the total thing in one function.

Best way for multiple functions is to create as module.

Hope it helps you.